# Call webservice repeatingly, objective c

Tags: iphone, objective-c, web-services, loops, synchronization

I have a webservice that returning 20 results each time (it is a limitation of the service provider). I want to call this service 10-20 times repeatingly and update my UI each time. 
Is there best practice for this situation? I do not want to block the ui while calling the server. This causes problems if the user want to perform actions while the action in progress
(like navigating away from the current page)
Thanks!!!

Comment: you're right in that you don't want to block the UI while you wait for the webservice communication to finish. i'm not sure how you're interacting with the webservice (NSURLConnection?), but there should be asynchronous ways of doing it. if there are only synchronous methods, i would suggest looking into Grand Central Dispatch.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

what you can do is call the webservice in a background thread, collect the required data and jump back to main thread and update the UI.

We are doing the above(i.e jumping from background thread to main thread) because it is not recommended to update any UI in the background process.

you can call you webService in background by using

`[self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(MyWebService) withObject:nil];//you can pass any object if you have`

and to come back on main thread when the background task is over you can do..
`[self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(myMainFunction) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:YES];`

you can change the last parameter i.e. `waitUntilDone:No` also. By doing this, user will not have to wait till the UI is updated. they can carry there task.

you can use `NSTimer` for periodic calling your webService.

hope that helped :)

Comment: Thanks for responding. I am using aync call to the server using ASIHTTPRequest. My problem is synchronizing the responses and stopping the iterations when the user is doing something else, like going away from the page...

Comment: so you can put a bool value that will tell that the user is on that UI or not..if he navigate to a different view you can set the bool to yes and in your iterations put a condition that if that bool is yes then break that iteration..

Comment: That exactly what I did. But what if the user did a new search and the results of the last one are still on the way? I will get mixed results!!! (I cannot stop requests that are on the way...)

Comment: If you're creating a new search, there may be a cancel method on the ASIHTTPRequest, like there is on NSURLConnection. Set the connections delegate to nil, so that you don't receive any unwanted callbacks from it, then release it.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how you want to display the information.

If you're using the asynchronous connection (in my opinion, more effective than calling a synchronous connection in the background) and its delegate, it should not block the user interface:

```
- (void)loadData {
    NSString *urlString = @"http://www.stackoverflow.com";
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:request delegate:self];
}

// delegate methods
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response {
    // clear out or intialize instance data variable
    [myData setLength:0];
}


- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data {
    [myData appendData:data];
}


- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection {
    // convert data to whatever it's supposed to be (for example, array)
    NSString *dataString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:myData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    NSArray *dataArray = [parser parseStringToArray:dataString];

    [myArray addObjectsFromArray:dataArray];

    //update tableview either using reload data (instant) or using updates (for smooth animation)
}
```

You can then recall the loadData method at the end of didFinishLoading: method to loop it.